# Characterizing differences of squares in $\mathbb Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

It is well known that a natural number can be written as a difference of two squares iff it is *not* of the form $4k+2$.

> I'm wondering if there is any characterization of which polynomials $f(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ with integer coefficients can be written as a difference $g(x)^2-h(x)^2$, for $f,g\in \mathbb Z[x]$.

I tried googling this, but any search involving "difference of squares" and "polynomial" invariably returns a list of pages explaining the simple algebraic rule $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.

Comment: The equality $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ is actually interesting: It implies that a natural number is a difference of two squares iff it is of the form $n(n+2m)$ for certain $n,m$, and these numbers are precisely the ones not of the form $4k+2$. (because they are odd, if $n$ is odd, and multiples of $4$ is $n$ is even)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is the type of characterization you are looking for:

**Lemma** Let $f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ be a polynomial. Then $f$ is a difference of two squares if and only if $f$ can be factored as 
$$f(x)=u(x)v(x) \mbox{ with } \\
u(x), v(x) \in \mathbb Z[x] \mbox{ and } u(x)-v(x) \in 2 \mathbb Z[x]$$

The proof is trivial, set $u=g-h$ and $v=g+h$.

So the problem reduces to the factorization of $f$. If $f$ is primitive and irreducible for example then it can be written as a difference of squares if and only is $f+1 \in 2\mathbb Z[x]$.

Also if $f$ is non-primitive, and we write $f=ag$ with $a \in \mathbb Z, g \in \mathbb Z[x]$, $g$ primitive, the answer is trivial if $a$ is even: if $a=4k$ then the answer is yes, while if $a=4k+2$ the answer is no.

But if $f$ has many factors, there might be many cases to check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I was hoping for a characterization which does not require me to know how to factor $f(x)$. In fact, in the situation I have in mind, I have a family of primitive polynomials which I suspect are irreducible, but it would be enough for me to show they can't be a difference of two squares, which I was hoping was an easier problem.